# Android KitKat screen processing

Tags: android, adb, screenshot, android-4.4-kitkat

As I know Google added possibility to capture screen using adb in Android 4.4 with 30 fps. Is there exist any way to transfer screen from Android 4.4 device with such speed? I used framebuffer, but it's too slow.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There is no such way. Neither USB nor WLAN is fast enough to transmit uncompressed high-resolution video at 30fps. You could try to do real-time compression on the device and transmit compressed video, but I suspect that that will starve the app you're recording of CPU and thereby make the recording unrealistic.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please provide me some example how I can compress or scale image on the device and than process it through adb? Thanks